# How can I know whether the eraser is active?

Tags: react-native, react-native-sketch-canvas

I am using the package - https://github.com/terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas

How can I know whether the eraser is active?
I want to change the eraser component color when the eraser is active.

I am using below component for showing whiteboard:

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround as below:

```
eraseComponent={<View onTouchStart={() => this.setState({eraserActive: true})}>
    <Text>Eraser</Text>
</View>}

strokeSelectedComponent={(color, index, changed) => {
    if (changed) {
        this.setState({eraserActive: false})
    }
    .
    .
    .
})
```